# React Native Firebase Functions on Expo not running

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo, react-native-firebase

I am using React Native Firebase Functions in my Expo project and there is no config plugin for it yet. When I run the project I get an error message saying:

> You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.functions(). Ensure you have either linked the module or added it to your projects Podfile.

It tells me to go to [invertase.link/ios](https://invertase.link/ios), but I don't think they have the solution there. Bear in mind I don't have an iOS directory because I'm using Expo. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

When installing these functions I had to use --legacy-peer-deps because it was conflicting with the version of firebase app. I'm not sure whether that has anything to do with my current problem.